# getRequest() returns "GET" when posting form

Tags: php, symfony

We are developing two separate sites on Symfony2 and encountered a strange problem on both of them when processing submitted forms.

Both sites have an action that is used for both displaying the form and handling submission. As it handles both GET and POST requests, `$this->getRequest()->getMethod()` is checked. If it is GET, we display the form. If it is POST, we persist it into an entity.

However, `getMethod()` seems to always return `GET` even when posting the data. I know the request method should be `POST` because the browser's network inspector says it sent the form as a POST request and `var_dump($_POST);` outputs the contents of the form we just submitted.

The sites are running on separate servers, both CentOS 6.3. I have a third similar server running a third site which handles the submissions fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: Is the form shown via a sub-request?

Comment: @elnur: It is, actually. Can we somehow access the main request from withing the sub-request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had such a problem several times and tried different approaches to it. Here's my last one:

```php
public function formAction(Request $request)
{
}
```

```
{% render 'Bundle:Controller:form' with {'request': app.request} %}
```

Note that you need to get the request as a parameter in this case — instead of fetching it from the container. If you're using Symfony idiomatically, then you're doing that already.

If you'll ever find a better way of solving this problem, I'm eager to know it. :)

Comment: This is so common... I just spent 2h trying to figure this out... Then now I remember. I opened a bug about this, nothing is done: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7551