# Why getMethod() returns "GET" instead of "POST"?

Tags: symfony

The goal is to submit a POST form with two radiobuttons (tipo) and a text field (numero) to make a query in my DB and show the data to the user.

I am trying to submit the form below, however when I submit the form, the request coming accross is a 'GET REQUEST'. The form is in "SupuestoConfig.html.twig":

```
<div id="cuadro">
<form id="configurador" action="{{ path('configsup') }}" method="POST">
    <p class="titulo_configurador">Elija supuesto penal:</p>
        {{ form_row(form.tipo) }}
    {{ form_row(form.numero, { 'label' : ' ', 'attr' : { 'class' : 'rec3' }}) }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    <input type="submit" name="cargar" value="Cargar" class="inputbt"/>
</form>
</div>
```

I render the previous form in "principal.html.twig":

```
{{ render(controller('PprsBundle:Default:SupuestoConfig'), {'strategy': 'inline'}) }}
```

My "Controller.php":

```
/**
     * @Route("/pprs/principal/supuesto={numero_supuesto}", name="configsup")
     * @Template("PprsBundle:Default:SupuestoConfig.html.twig")
     */
    public function SupuestoConfigAction($numero_supuesto = null)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
            ->add('tipo', 'choice', array(
                                    'choices' => array(
                                          'aleatorio' => 'Aleatorio',
                                          'pornumero' => 'Por número'),
                                    'multiple' => false,
                                    'expanded' => true,
                                    'data' => 'aleatorio'
         ))

         // This add may contains error
        ->add('numero', 'text', array('label' => ' ','disabled' => true))
     ->getForm();

     $peticion = $this->getRequest();


echo ('<script type="text/javascript">alert ("'.$peticion->getMethod().'");</script>');// Returns 'GET'

if ($peticion->isMethod('POST')) {
    // Symfony2.2
    $form->bind($peticion);

    **$datos = $form->getData();**


    *//foreach(array_keys($datos) as $p) {
    //echo ('<script type="text/javascript">alert ("'.$datos.'");</script>');
    //}*

    if ($form->isValid()) { ... }
```

In Controller.php, despite I´ve got a GET request (when I remove the line 
`->add('numero', 'text',..`
 I´ve got a POST request, why is that?), in getData I don´t get the text field.

Finally, my routing.yml:

```
pprs_principal:
    pattern:  /pprs/principal/supuesto={numero_supuesto}/
    defaults: { _controller: PprsBundle:Default:principal, numero_supuesto: 1 }

_pprs_principal:
    pattern:  /pprs/principal/
    defaults: { _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect, route: pprs_principal }
```

Sorry for my bad english, Thanks in advance

Edit:

1) Anybody knows why I obtain a GET request instead of a POST when I add the text field in my createFormBuilder?

2) Anybody knows why Don't I get the text field when I call getData?

Help me please...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer could help you out:

[getRequest() returns "GET" when posting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123559/getrequest-returns-get-when-posting-form)

Basically, when rendering a form with a {% render %} tag, it actually creates "another" request... It doesn't pass in the locale, the method, etc.

I opened a bug about this, and it went as By Design:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7551